# How could I delete sql functions format in awk?

Tags: sql, regex, awk

I've got a sql query which looks like this:

```
SELECT test1(func1(MYFIELD)), 
       test2(MAX(MYFIELD), LOWER("NOPE")),
       test3(MAX(MYFIELD), 1234),
       AVG(test1(test2(MYFIELD, func1(4)))),
       func2(UPPER("stack"))
       SUBSTR(MYFIELD, 2, 4),
       test2(MIN(MYFIELD), SUBSTR(LOWER(UPPER("NOPE")), 1, 7)),
       SUBSTR('func1(', 2, 4)
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Then I'm trying to remove all functions called:

- test1
- test2
- test3
- func1
- func2

But preserving the *AVG, MAX, UPPER, SUBSTR*... and all native functions.

So the desired output would be:

```
SELECT MYFIELD, 
       MAX(MYFIELD),
       MAX(MYFIELD),
       AVG(MYFIELD),
       UPPER("stack")
       SUBSTR(MYFIELD, 2, 4),
       MIN(MYFIELD)
       SUBSTR('func1(', 2, 4)
FROM MYTABLE;
```

I want to remove the *LOWER* of the second line because, it is an argument of one of the functions to delete, in this case test2, which has two parameters. Then if we delete the function, we should delete its params as well.

I've tried to do it by this way in awk:

```
{
    print gensub(/(test1|test2|func1|func2)\(/,"","gi", $0);
}
```

But the output doesn't have into account the right parentheses, it doesn't also delete the rest of parameters of the custom functions:

```
SELECT MYFIELD)),
       MAX(MYFIELD), LOWER("NOPE")),
       MAX(MYFIELD), 1234),
       AVG(MYFIELD, 4)))),
       UPPER("stack"))
       SUBSTR(MYFIELD, 2, 4),
       MIN(MYFIELD), SUBSTR(LOWER(UPPER("NOPE")), 1, 7)),
       SUBSTR('', 2, 4)
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Any idea or clue to handle this situation?

Comment: why is `, LOWER("NOPE")` missing from expected output? and what's the rule to remove or not remove contents inside `test/func`?

Comment: True, but it is an argument of one of the functions to delete, in this case to test2 which has two parameters. Then if we delete the function, we should delete its params as well.

Comment: Done! Thank you for your time, @Sundeep! :)

Comment: Nope, it's not mandatory. We could have `test2(MAX(MYFIELD), 1234),`, for instance. (I'm gonna update the main post again).

Comment: try `sed -E 's/(test[123]|func[12])\(([^,]*),[^)]*\)/\2/; :a s/(test[123]|func[12])\(([^)]*)\)/\2/; ta; s/\)\),/),/' file`

Comment: Wow, you are near to the final solution! But I've added a new case which you didn't contemplate. Check it out, plz

Comment: nope, my solution isn't truly aware of nesting, I was adding patch after patch :P.. for latest case, patch would be `sed -E 's/(test[123]|func[12])\(([^,]*),[^)]*\)/\2/; :a s/(test[123]|func[12])\(([^)]*)\)/\2/; ta; s/\)\),/),/; s/\),[^)]*\)\),/),/' file`... but that will not be robust

Comment: I've added the last casuistic (I promise). It is quite weird, I know... lol

Answer (score -1):

you could just rename functions' names to built-in function`COALESCE` while keep the brakets `(` `)` and other params of users' functions.
It will produce the same result, not syntactically, but it will work the same **UNLESS** the built-in functions don't return `NULL` values. It will be much easier to achieve because you don't have to worry about brakets.

If `file` is an input you provide, then:

`cat file | sed 's#\(test1\|test2\|func1\|func2\)(#COALESCE(#g'`

will produce:

```
SELECT COALESCE(COALESCE(MYFIELD)),
    COALESCE(MAX(MYFIELD), 4),
    AVG(COALESCE(COALESCE(MYFIELD, COALESCE(4)))),
    COALESCE(UPPER("stack"))
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: This one `test2(MAX(MYFIELD), 4),` will produce a problem as it reduces to `(MAX(MYFIELD), 4),`, won't it?

Comment: yes, you are right, of course. ok... I will try to figure out it

Comment: if you don't carry about `NULL` values which possibly could be returned by built-in functions you can change user functions into built-in function `COALESCE` which returns the first non-NULL value. Then you don't have to carry about removing the rest of parameters. `cat file | sed 's#\(test1\|test2\|func1\|func2\)(#COALESCE(#g'`